# jquery change button id

Tags: jquery, button

How can I change the id of a button during a function run?

I've tried:

```
$('#follow').attr('id','unfollow');
```

But no luck when i try to run a `$("#unfollow").click(function(){` function.

How can I do this?

### update

```
$(function() { 

  $("#follow").click(function(){ 
    $('#follow').attr('id','unfollow'); 
    alert("follow");
    });

  $(document).on('click', '#unfollow', function() {
    $('#unfollow').attr('id','follow'); 
    alert("unfollow"); 
    });

});
```

Comment: You must attach your event handler after the ID has been changed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code you wrote should work, but are you binding the click event after you change the id attribute ?

If not, then use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead to bind the click event.

```
$(document).on('click', '#unfollow', function() { ... });
```

By the way:

I don't believe that changing an element's ID is a good practice. IDs should be unique on the page.

Why not do this by changing the elements class (using [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) methods) or by adding a data to the element (by the [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method)?

**Update**

Try something like this :

```
$(document).on('click', '.follow', function() {
    alert('follow');
    $(this).removeClass('follow').addClass('unfollow');
});
$(document).on('click', '.unfollow', function() {
    alert('unfollow');
    $(this).removeClass('unfollow').addClass('follow');
});
```

**Note how I used selectors that use class' instead of the id, so you must give the element the proper class (follow/unfollow for the initial state)

Comment: `on` doesn't work that way, you can't just replace `live` with `on`.  `on` is used for *ALL* event binding, not just "live" events.  It should be `$(document).on('click', '#unfollow', function(){`.

Comment: dont suggest `.live` its deprecated. "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers." http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: true - I'm so used to using this method because of some legacy code in our code base at work... :) sorry...

Comment: the class attribute is in use from my css formatting though. When I do this method you've posted, it runs the #follow function again straight after its ran the #unfollow one.

Comment: that's exactly why you should use classes, and have the selector you bind the method to more specific, using a class that is only relevant to the situation you want. This should work, I've done it hundreds of times, literally!

Answer (score 1):

In order to attach an event to an element which does not exists yet, you have to use [$.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$("#unfollow").live('click', function(){
```

Comment: `.live` is deprecated, use `.on`.

Comment: it's not clear which version of jQuery is used, but the linked documentation clearly states that as of 1.7 it's deprecated

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#follow').attr('id','unfollow');
```

After changing the `id` then:

FIRST try this:

```
$("#unfollow").click(function(){

});
```

Otherwise live event:

```
$('body').on('click', '#unfollow', function(){

});
```

**NOTE:** `live()` is deprecated. So try like second one if you need really a live event, and user jQuery 1.7.x

Comment: `$(body).on(` doesn't work.  That should be `$(document.body).on(` or `$('body').on(`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$("#unfollow").click(function(){` only binds to the `$("#unfollow")` element if it exists at that time.  My guess is you're binding the click event elsewhere, before you change the ID.

You can make it a live event, like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '#unfollow', function(){
```

NOTE: Instead of `document` you should use a closer parent element of `#unfollow`.  Just make sure that element stays in the DOM, if it's removed, so is the event.

Or, you can re-bind the event (using `$("#unfollow").click(function(){`) after you change the ID:

```
$('#follow').attr('id','unfollow');
$("#unfollow").click(function(){
```